# Why is everybody suddenly on good terms with Grom Hellscream?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

At the start of Warlords of Draenor, we find out Grom Hellscream is the leader of the Iron Horde and he is bent on conquering all of Draenor and any other land he can reach.  In fact, most of our questing experience is seeing how the Iron Horde has assimilated the orc tribes and devastated the lives of everyone else living there, under the orders of Grom.

Then, at the end of the legendary ring chain in 6.1 we watch as Guldan seizes control of the Iron Horde and Grom is captured.

In Hellfire Citadel, we free him and he shows up in the fight against Archimonde.  However, after Archimonde is defeated, we see Durotan, Yrel, and Khadgar all celebrating alongside Grom, and all their animosity seems to have vanished.

Why has everybody suddenly forgiven Grom as if the events prior to 6.2 never happened?

Comment: Please note that spoiler tags are only to be used if the main body makes perfect sense without the spoilered text

Comment: @Timelord64 uh, no. The spoiler tags are for spoilers. If main text doesn't make sense anymore, you are free to read the spoilers, or try to understand what you can.

Comment: @Lohoris, I am not telling you my opinion, I am telling you what was decided upon, on meta.

Comment: @Lohoris - see http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/9809/28182 and http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7133/28182

Answer (score 3):

Grom redeemed himself when he refused to drink the demon blood a second time, with intent to never be enslaved. When doing so he moved to attack Gul'dan outright physically. Though he was handled easily by Gul'dan this turned him into at least opposing the same enemies as us heroes in the story. There are quite a few communities debating if he deserved this redemption story and to what degree this was glazed over by Blizzard.

Most useful 2 references: http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Grommash_Hellscream and http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/1806309-Should-Grom-be-forgiven-(Spoilers)

Comment: This is at least written to sound like speculation

Comment: @Timelord64 Thanks, you are right, corrected to currently known aspects of the story to remove the second portion that included speculation.

Comment: I think the problem is that this question calls for speculation, in general. Too difficult to say with what I know of the game.

Comment: I can understand why they would let Grom fight Archimonde, but I'm not sure why they're celebrating with him.  When we dropped Garrosh in MoP, the alliance immediately was demanding reparations from the horde.  I guess there isn't an in-game explanation yet, but Blizzard has a tendency of late to offload a bunch of key story moments into other media like the book series that I don't follow.

Comment: I agree, I will provide an update to the answer once we discover more lore wise. We are late expansion so I expect some heavy clean up in the future from Blizzard in form of books or supplemental cinematic before Legion.